# navigate.push is not redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

Im trying to redirect the user after a successful log in. So everything works but when it comes to redirecting, it doesn't work.
Im using react-router-dom v6 so I had to use useNavigate() instead of useHistory(). Im new to using react and will appreciate any insights on the matter. Here is my code-:

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../../../layouts/frontend/Navbar';
import axios from 'axios';
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Login() {

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [loginInput, setLogin] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
        error_list: [],
    });

    const handleInput = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        setLogin({...loginInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    }

    const loginSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = {
            email: loginInput.email,
            password: loginInput.password,
        }

        axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
            axios.post(`api/login`, data).then(res => {
                if(res.data.status === 200){
                    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.data.token);
                    localStorage.setItem('auth_name', res.data.username);
                    swal("Success",res.data.message,"success");
                    navigate.push('/');
                }
                else if(res.data.status === 401)
                {
                    swal("Warning",res.data.message,"warning"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    setLogin({...loginInput, error_list: res.data.validation_errors });
                }
            });
        });
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <Auth/>                
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: What is Auth in jsx? When loginSubmit is triggered?

Comment: are you sure you are getting into the `if(res.data.status === 200)` ? I do not see any call to the `loginSubmit` which should trigger the navigation